# Let $M$ be a surface. Prove that if the asymptotic curves of $M$ are orthogonal then $M$ is minimal.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential

Could you help me about differential geometry? I can not prove the following proposition.

Let $M$ be a surface. Prove that if the asymptotic curves of $M$ are orthogonal then $M$ is minimal.

Comment: Your question could use some improvement. Take a look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for general tips on how to write a good question. For specifics: you can improve your title by [making your title your question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144); you could [add context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) by including your own work on this question, and by indicating some definitions of terms to make your question more understable.